# OpenVPN on startup fails

Tags: boot, static-ip, vpn

Whenever I reboot my RPi, the openvpn service fails to start. The relevant line from the log says: `[...] TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET]192.168.1.2:1194: Cannot assign requested address` (Full log [here](https://gist.github.com/Kab00se/8cef28738defe7205cd6))

When I start the service manually (with `openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpnserver.conf`) it starts properly though.

My RPi is properly setup with a static IP (192.168.1.2), so I'm guessing that the IP isn't properly configured when it tries to start the openvpn service on start-up. Is there a way to check/fix this?

Comment: how do you start your service? /etc/rc.local or services?

Comment: I looked around `/etc/init.d` and found a script called `openvpn` with [these contents](https://gist.github.com/Kab00se/c2bedcebbc5f4654f664). I'm not terribly familiar with linux so I'm not sure if I can find it elsewhere. I saw no mention of it in rc.local.

Comment: if you are using Raspbian you can use raspi-config to wait for the network to be up before continuing to boot.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to sudo crontab -e: @reboot sleep 20; /etc/init.d/openvpn start

...this is a delayed restart of openvpn when the pi starts.

Comment: Explain to the original poster what this command does...

Comment: Pretty straight forward, but done.

Comment: Having tried all sorts of different `After=` and `Wants=` in the SystemD unit file for OpenVPN without fixing the problem, this was the solution that worked. Of course you should also disable the OpenVPN unit with `systemctl disable openvpn`, so it doesn't try starting it twice.

Answer (score -2):

Comment out the line with local in your openvpnserver.conf file and it will probably  work after a reboot.